# Jquery autocomplete pass selected values to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I saw a thread a while back regarding this unfortunately I forgot to mark it as a favorite and now I can't find it, I have jQuery auto complete wired up in to my page.

When I type and select an item I need to pass it back to the controller when pressing submit, when inspecting the HTML after selecting it looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-autocomplete-multiselect ui-state-default ui-widget" style="width: 746.6px;">
<div class="ui-autocomplete-multiselect-item">
        Windsurfing
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
</div>
<div class="ui-autocomplete-multiselect-item">
       Surfing
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
</div>
    <input id="myAutocomplete" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 19px;">
</div>
```

I need to some how pass back the Windsurfing and surfing values I've tried using the FormCollection but that doesn't seem to pass it back

Comment: Your input does not have a name attribute so it does not post back its value (use view models, bind to it using strongly typed html helpers and post back the model to avoid these types of errors in your code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sounds interesting, I believe the thread I saw originally was doing exactly that, do you have an example? or maybe seen the thread im talking about?

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/04/23/asp-net-mvc-amp-jquery-ui-autocomplete.aspx) might help

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've just gone through that article and made a working example, what he has suggested is having multiple textbox's on show that allow the user to choose one item then move to the next text box and start typing again. This is not what I want, the best way to explain my functionality is look at how you add tags to new question here on stackoverflow I have enable multiselect on my autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

When binding the autocomplete widget to your input, just create a select event handler like this:

```
$( "#myAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    // pass back to controller here
  }
});
```

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for, I want the user to choose what he/she wants and when they are finished and submits the page I then want to reference them I don't want to keep making calls to the controller everytime someone selects something new

Answer (score 0):

Calling the controller on select might not be appropriate, that is like having an old style postback, not the way you want to do it in my opinion. A better way would be to set the value of the selection to a hidden property on the model.

```
$( "#myAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
   select: function( event, ui ) {
   $('#yourHiddenModelField').val(ui.item.value);
   }
});
```